Josephson critical current expression
In the Barone's Physical Applications of the Josephson Effect there is the derivation of the critical current density of a Josephson junction
$$
J_c=\frac{2 K}{\hbar}\rho 
$$
where $K$ is the coupling coefficient such that $\hat H_T= K \left[ |L\rangle \langle R  | + |R\rangle \langle L  | \right]$ and $ \rho = |\psi|^2$ is the Cooper pair density. Doing a Dimensional analysis I don't get $A/m^2$, in fact if $[K]$=J, $[\hbar]$=Js and $[\rho]$=1/m $^2$  I get
$$
[J_c]= \frac{J}{Js}\frac{1}{m^2}=\frac{1}{m^2s}
$$
any suggestion ?
